# Open example.com, but all links point to an IP

Tags: nginx, domain, ip, mask

I own a domain, let's say `example.com`, and I point an A record to my server with IP `123.123.123.123`, running nginx. When I open example.com in a browser, I get to the correct site, but all links point to the IP instead of the domain.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a web server issue?

Comment: you are so right! Thanks! I somehow thought this was a masking or redirecting thing... but it was just Wordpress setting links wrong.

Comment: @AD7six - maybe post that as an answer so sweenytimm can accept it

Answer (score 1):

nginx isn't (directly) responsible for how links are rendered in your html pages.

why not just use `/foo` instead of `http://<some variable>/foo` in your php files?